# Dynamic cumulative summations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, replace, cumsum

In the following DataFrame, the column `B` computes the sum of column `A` from index `0` to `n`.

```
ix    A      B
---------------
 0     1     1
 1     1     2
 2     1     3
 3     1     4
 4     2     6
 5    -1     5
 6    -3     2
```

Alternatively, the column `B` sums `1` for each `type == 'I'` and `-1` for each `type == 'O'`.

```
ix   type     B
----------------
 0      I     1
 1      I     2
 2      O     1
 3      I     2
 4      O     1
 5      O     0
 6      I     1
```

How to perform this type of calculations, where the `n-th` result of one column depends on the aggregated results of another column, up to `n`?

Comment: Look at `cumsum` and `expanding`.

Comment: @IanS should do the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['C'] = df.A.cumsum()
print (df)
   ix  A  B  C
0   0  1  1  1
1   1  1  2  2
2   2  1  3  3
3   3  1  4  4
4   4  2  6  6
5   5 -1  5  5
6   6 -3  2  2
```

And for second `df` add [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
df['C'] = df.type.map({'I':1, 'O':-1}).cumsum()
print (df)
   ix type  B  C
0   0    I  1  1
1   1    I  2  2
2   2    O  1  1
3   3    I  2  2
4   4    O  1  1
5   5    O  0  0
6   6    I  1  1
```

Or:

```
df['C'] = df.type.replace({'I':1, 'O':-1}).cumsum()
print (df)
   ix type  B  C
0   0    I  1  1
1   1    I  2  2
2   2    O  1  1
3   3    I  2  2
4   4    O  1  1
5   5    O  0  0
6   6    I  1  1
```